# Get property name and type using lambda expression

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I am trying to write a function that will pull the name of a property and the type using syntax like below:

```
private class SomeClass
{
    Public string Col1;
}

PropertyMapper<Somewhere> propertyMapper = new PropertyMapper<Somewhere>();
propertyMapper.MapProperty(x => x.Col1)
```

Is there any way to pass the property through to the function without any major changes to this syntax?

I would like to get the property name and the property type.

So in the example below i would want to retrieve

`Name = "Col1"` and `Type = "System.String"`

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the bigger picture?  Why not just pass "Col1" as a string name and use reflection to find that member?  What motivates the lambda?

Comment: I'm working on an in house ORM for my work. I want to easily support changing property names without having to search string all over the place, plus it give (in my opinion) a clean syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here's enough of an example of using [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) to get the name of a property or field to get you started:

```
public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
{
    var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member != null)
        return member.Member;

    throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a member access", "expression");
}
```

Calling code would look like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "My Program"; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MemberInfo member = ReflectionUtility.GetMemberInfo((Program p) => p.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(member.Name);
    }
}
```

A word of caution, though: the simple statment of `(Program p) => p.Name` actually involves quite a bit of work (and can take measurable amounts of time). Consider caching the result rather than calling the method frequently.

Comment: Always remember that a lambda expression can be converted into either a delegate or an expression tree.

Comment: Caveat: GetMemberInfo implementation is not very safe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658669/lambda-expression-not-returning-expected-memberinfo. That said you can use it just to read the name. But the returned member info itself wont be accurate.

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily done in C# 6. To get the name of property use nameof operator.

```
nameof(User.UserId)
```

and to get type of property use typeof operator.

```
typeof(User.UserId)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this very useful.

```
public class PropertyMapper<T>
{
    public virtual PropertyInfo PropertyInfo<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member != null && member.Member is PropertyInfo)
            return member.Member as PropertyInfo;

        throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a Property", "expression");
    }

    public virtual string PropertyName<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
    {
        return PropertyInfo<U>(expression).Name;
    }

    public virtual Type PropertyType<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
    {
        return PropertyInfo<U>(expression).PropertyType;
    }
}
```

I made this little class to follow the original request.
If you need the name of the property you can use it like this:

```
PropertyMapper<SomeClass> propertyMapper = new PropertyMapper<SomeClass>();
string name = propertyMapper.PropertyName(x => x.Col1);
```

Answer (score 3):

I just thought I would put this here to build on the previous approach.

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string PropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member != null && member.Member is PropertyInfo)
            return member.Member.Name;

        throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a Property", "expression");
    }
}
```

You can then call it in the following fashion:

```
Helpers.PropertyName(() => TestModel.TestProperty);
```

I should also point out that with VS 2015 and C# 6.0 you can simply use nameof.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx