# Can I get specific metadata from a Func<T, object>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, reflection

Consider the following code:

```
string propertyName;
var dateList = new List<DateTime>() { DateTime.Now };
propertyName = dateList.GetPropertyName(dateTimeObject => dateTimeObject.Hour);

// I want the propertyName variable to now contain the string "Hour"
```

Here is the extension method:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, object> func) {
   //TODO: would like to dynamically determine which 
   // property is being used in the func function/lambda
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I thought that maybe this other method, using `Expression<Func<T, object>>` instead of `Func<T, object>` would give me more power to find what I need, but I am at a loss at how.

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(this IList<T> list, Expression<Func<T, object>> expr) {
   // interrogate expr to get what I want, if possible
}
```

This is the first time I have done anything this deep with Linq, so maybe I am missing something obvious. Basically I like the idea of passing in lambdas, so that I get compile-time checking, but I don't know that my idea on how I can use them in this particular case will work.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get method name and type using lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-method-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the version I use, it returns a `PropertyInfo`, but getting the name is trivial.

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)  
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

    if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
    {
        memberExpression = ((UnaryExpression) expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
    }
    else if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
        memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    }

    if (memberExpression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a member access", "expression");
    }

    return memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this was perfect. Now my hack is complete! :P Ah, I hate having to come up with these workarounds to get stuff to work "like it should." I mean, it's fun and all, but just too painful when there is real work to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

here is a very easy and fast way to do it on this blog: http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,206e64d1-29ae-4362-874b-83f5b103727f.aspx

> So given:
>
> Func func = Name =>
>   "Value";
>
> You can get the lambda parameter
>   "Name" from the function delegate by
>   calling:
>
> func.Method.GetParameters()[0].Name
>   (would return "Name")
>
> Here's the revised Hash method from
>   Andrey:

```
public Dictionary<string, T> Hash<T>(params Func<string, T>[] args)
where T : class
{
    var items = new Dictionary<string, T>();
    foreach (var func in args)
    {
        var item = func(null);
        items.Add(func.Method.GetParameters()[0].Name, item);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Hope it helps,
Patrick

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(this IList<T> list, Expression<Func<T, object>> expr) {
  MemberExpression member_expression = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
  if (member_expression == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("member_expression");
  MemberInfo member = member_expression.Member;
  PropertyInfo property = member as PropertyInfo;
  string proname = memeber.name;
}
```

WARNING: Air Code!

Comment: Thanks for answering Nathan, I appreciate it. You were close enough, and since you said "something like this should do the trick," you were not technically wrong! I will accept @gcores' answer because his was correct without me having to make changes. I still gave you a +1 for answering though!

Comment: Theres a minor difference between Nathan's and gcores's answers with regard to some fringe cases such as nullable decimals (if I remember correctly!). For those properties the body of the expression isn't a MemberExpression but a UnaryExpression (dealt with in gcores's answer).

Comment: @Jason Thats cool, I would have accepted his answer as well as it is more complete then mine.

Comment: @sighohwell: I know, that is why I accepted @gcores' answer and felt that @Nathan's was good enough to deserve some credit, since it would have helped point me in the right direction if @gcores hadn't posted.

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note: **func.Method.GetParameters()[0].Name** is extremelly fast when compared with compiling the lambda and extracting the member expression, then the member info, then the name.