# How to get name of a class property?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, gettype

Is there anyway I can get the name of class property `IntProperty`?

```
public class ClassName
{
  public static int IntProperty { get { return 0; } }
}

//something like below but I want to get the string of "IntProperty"
ClassName.IntProperty.GetType().Name
```

Basically what I want to do is to dynamically save property name string into the database, and later on retrieve it from the database and invoke the property dynamically.

Seems like what I am looking for is similar to duck typing I think.

Thanks!

UPDATED:

This is the actual code. This is more like a workflow kind of thing. But each task is defined as property of a class (class is used to group tasks).

```
public class ApplicationTask
{
    public static Task<string> SendIncompleteNotification
    {
        get
        {
            return new Task<string>
                (
                a => Console.WriteLine("Sample Task")
                , "This is a sample task which does nothing."
                );
        }
    }
}
```

So, the code will be able to retrieve the full name of the class and property something like: `namespace.ApplicationTask.SendIncompleteNotification` and save this into the database. Later on, the code will read the string and dynamically create the task and pass it into another to execute.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579963/can-i-get-specific-metadata-from-a-funct-object

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301809/workarounds-for-nameof-operator-in-c-typesafe-databinding

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get method name and type using lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-method-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of `ClassName.IntProperty` is just an integer value. As soon as it's executed and the result is returned, there's no trace of it having come from `IntProperty`.

If you're using .NET 3.5 you can use an expression tree instead, usually created via a lambda expression:

```
Expression<Func<int>> exp = () => ClassName.IntProperty;
```

You can then compile and execute the expression *and* separately find out what it's doing (retrieving `IntProperty` in this case). I'm not really sure whether this is suitable for what you want to do though.

If you *do* work out how to save the property name in the database, then `GetProperty` is the way to go on the retrieval front.

Perhaps if you could give more context in the question in terms of how you want to use this, we could help more. You've shown just an expression - if you could show it in terms of where you'd be using it, that would be great.

EDIT: You've expanded the property, but not how it's being called. Do you *need* to call it directly, rather than just fetching the list of properties using `Type.GetProperties` and storing the list of property names in the database?

Again, if you could show the code which *calls* the property, and how you want it to interact with the database, we may be able to make more progress.

Comment: See also the discussion here (and other places): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression/

Answer (score 73):

With C#6.0 you can get it by

```
nameof(ClassName.IntProperty)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Seems the only sane way to selectively bind to a specific property on a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: This just made a lot of my code so much easier to refactor! I have a ListCollectionView in my view model and the only way to setup some of the sorting and such is string version of the property name. `GamesView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(Game.IsFavorited), ListSortDirection.Descending));`

Answer (score 34):

I think that the use of the [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) method in this case, is redundant, because you need to know the property name to call the method.

You could loop through your properties and extract its name:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(ClassName).GetProperties())
{
    string propertyName = p.Name;
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Type objectType = this.GetType();
PropertyInfo property = objectType.GetProperty("intProperty");
System.Console.Write(property.Name);
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: sorry it's not what i wanted. i've edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: What if you decide to change the name of "intProperty"? You would have to remember to change this, too. Imho it's bad practice to spread those magic strings around in your codebase. I'd highly recommend to use something like nameof(ClassName.IntProperty) as wintersolider pointed out.

Comment: to get property name we are using the property name string :). c# 6 you can use nameof(class.property). if you rename property somewere else then you will surely get compilation errors for nameof

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `nameof(ClassName.IntProperty)`
It will give you "IntProperty"

Answer (score -5):

I came across this, and it seems very helpful for getting property name. (C++)

```
#define getVarName(varName,holder) sprintf(holder, "%s", #varName)

int main() {
    int var = 100; // just any type of identifier
    char name[100]; // it will get the variables name
    getVarName(var, name);
    puts(name);
    return 0;
}
```

ref: http://zobayer.blogspot.com/2010/05/c-fun-get-variables-name.html

Comment: The question explicitly mentioned c#. I suggest you post a code conversion as C++ may not be able to convert to c# easily.