# Is it possible to get an object property name string without creating the object instance?

Tags: c#, lambda, properties

A **string representation** of an object instance property can be taken with `Expression<Func<T>>`:

```
string propertyName = ((MemberExpression) property.Body).Member.Name;
```

But what if I don't have (don't want to create) the instance? How do I get the property name in this case?

**Explained**

I need a string representation of a property name of some object.

Let's say there is an entity

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}
```

Now I want to pass the key expression of this entity to some other function, thus I need the string "ID", but I don't want to hardcode the string like `SomeOtherFunction("ID")`, instead I use the expression `SomeOtherFunction(ExpressionReader.GetString(() => CustomerInstance.ID))`. For this to work I need to supply the entity instance.

Now I want to do the same **without** creating the instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the instance"? You don't need to create an instance of the class that exposes the property, but obviously you need an instance of `Expression<T>`.

Comment: you are aware of typeof(myClass).GetProperty("abc"), right?

Comment: What's the difference between hardcoding the ID property, and the "ID" string?

Comment: @SWeko when there is a need to change prop name `ID` to `NewId` Visual Studio will do it for you in all referenced places :-) - maybe there are more reasons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get property name and type using lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-property-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is possible with a method signature like the following:

```
private static string GetPropertyName<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;

    return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

You can call this method without an instance of the customer class:

```
string propertyName = GetPropertyName((Customer c) => c.ID);
```

Of course you should add some checks for correct expression types before you cast to `MemberExpression` and access `memberExpression.Member.Name`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you dont need an instance to decompose the `Expression`. Even if the expression expects one, you will never invoke it.

In fact, you do it just like you did in first code snippet.

You would change you code to look like this then:

```
SomeOtherFunction(ExpressionReader<Customer>.GetString(c => c.ID))
```

Does that make sense to you?

Alternatively:

```
Customer c = null; // null intentionally

SomeOtherFunction(ExpressionReader.GetString(() => c.ID));
```

Still no problem as you are not invoking the expression.

Comment: @net_prog: You will have to modify your code, that is just 1 possible suggestion, may are possible.

Answer (score 3):

With the new **nameof** operator of C# 6 I would suggest the following:

```
 private string GetNameMyProperty1(TestC c = null)
 {
     return nameof(c.MyProperty1);
 }
```

Comment: You don't even need an instance of the object. You can just do something like `nameof(TestC.MyProperty1)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean, but based on my understanding you could use Reflection. Using this approach, if you had the `Type` of what you wanted to get a property name from, then you could retrieve the properties using:

```
Type someType = typeof(SomeClass);

// Get all properties for a type
PropertyInfo[] properties = someType.GetProperties();

// Get a property from a type by it's name
PropertyInfo property = someType.GetProperty("PropertyName");
```

Once you have instance(s) of the `PropertyInfo` class, you can retrieve information such as the property name.

For more information on this approach, see the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is good but does not cover UnaryExpressions. It will fail when trying to get the property of a DateTime:

```
    private static string GetPropertyName<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property)
    {
        if (property.Body is MemberExpression)
        {
            return ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            var op = ((UnaryExpression)property.Body).Operand;
            return ((MemberExpression)op).Member.Name;
        }  
    }
```