# Playing with Object Query "pattern" in C# and Expression Trees

Tags: c#, generics, objectquery

I am playing with a basic implementation of the Query Object "pattern" (in quotes since this is an implementation of the interpreter pattern), and I was thinking of an enhancement which I do not know how to implement.

As you know a Criterion object would look something like the following:

```
public class Criterion
{
  ...
  string FieldName { get; set; }
  string Value { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

What I do not like is the fact that I have to add the field a string so I was thinking if I could create some kind of generic Criterion class so I could use it like so:

```
var criterion = new Criterion<Person>();
criterion.Field = c => c.FirstName;
criterion.Value = "John";
```

or something along those lines.

Of course there also would be the part where the criteria needs to be converted into SQL so I could do something like:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE " + criteria.Field.ToString() + " = '" + criteria.Value + "'"
```

I am sure there's got to be a way of doing this but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get method name and type using lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-method-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pretty easily do this with Expressions. This article has an example - [Get property name and type using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-method-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)