# Using PropertyInfo as dictionary key

Tags: c#, reflection

I verified that GetHashCode and Equals allow PropertyInfo to be used as a dictionary key. (Specifically, the hash codes are the same and Equals returns true.)

Is it safe then, to use PropertyInfo as a dictionary key?  Is there something I am unaware of that makes them unsuitable as dictionary keys?

Basically, I'm trying to reference properties by lambda expressions as described here ([Get property name and type using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-property-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)) and I wish to cache my results.

Comment: Are you using one part of the PropertyInfo? I do not see how the return can be the same when you are most likely going to change something in the Property that will in turn change the hash.

Comment: I would post this at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) with a code example.

Comment: I think you pretty much answered the question yourself, I don't see why it wouldn't work. Indeed, `Dictionary` uses `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, if these return the desired values it should work ... Is there any reason why you fail unsafe doing this?

Answer (score 3):

PropertyInfo can be used as key of dictionary, the only performance hit can be how will you get a propertyinfo for dictionary usage.