# Want Func value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, delegates

Func func = a => a.Id;

I want to get Id from func. Not the value of Id.

func.invoke() give me the value of Id.

As Per suggested comment i tried this.
But i got member as null in GetMemberInfo method.
I want this approach. ie. i want store func in dictionary. then get that func from dictionary and get the name of Id .

```
public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member != null)
            return member.Member;

        throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a member access", "expression");
    }


static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<int, Func<Soure.Employee, int>> testDir = new Dictionary<int, Func<Soure.Employee, int>>();
            testDir.Add(1, p => p.Id);
            var testDirValue = testDir[1];
            Expression<Func<Soure.Employee, int>> expr1 = mc => testDirValue(mc);
            MemberInfo member = Program.GetMemberInfo(expr1);
            Console.WriteLine(member.Name);
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you have a specific problem? Asking people to read your code to understand what you are asking usually results in chasing them away, especially if the code is so large it can't fit in a single screen

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos  : As i already wrote ' I know its hard describe what i want. Thats why i am giving running code please debug it. You can get what i want.'    That why i had given the running code. So that anybody can understand it.

Comment: @HemantMalpote **Noone** is going to run your code to decipher what you are asking.  It seems as simple as 'I'm having trouble getting a value out of a dictionary' but to let me help you please ask a specific question.  Don't get me wrong... it's excellent that you provided all the code necessary to duplicate your problem... I really appreciate that... I just can't understand what the problem you are trying to solve is.

Comment: @ Kevin basically i am storing dictionary which contain key as Where To Map and Value as Func that will get execute and return value will be set to key. To execute func and assign value is later part. Now i want the property name which will be mapped to destination. And that value will be used in assigning values logic. If i wrote specified function i may need to explain a lot. Thats why i gave entire running code. So that anybody can run it .

Comment: @HemantMalpote Please edit your question and add this information... however I still don't understand what the problem you are having is.

Comment: @Kevin please debug the code. You can get what i want.

Comment: Guys i had made question very simple. If i get this one i will manage with previews synervie.

Comment: @HemantMalpote See if this is what you're looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression

Comment: There is a similar question on SO. Take a look at this [solution.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-property-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression

Comment: @D Stanley  and @Oliver your answer works in simple example. thanks for it. But my requirement is little different. For that i had added extra information in question please looked into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost answered your own question. Let's assume MydeptId takes no parameters and returns an int, then:

`Func<int> func = (a:SomeType) => a.MydeptId;`

Then you invoke the function thus:

`int i = func();`